# Extracting ToUnicode tables from PDF

Tags: pdf

Can anyone suggest an easy to implement way to extract ToUnicode tables from PDF? I can extract fonts using pdfextract from mupdf, now I'm looking for a way to extract ToUnicode tables for those fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify pdfextract to extract the ToUnicode CMaps (not tables, CMaps).

You might look at the code in savefont and add something like :

```
obj = fz_dict_gets(dict, "ToUnicode");
if (obj)
{
    stream = obj;
}
```

If there is a ToUnicode (there need not be) then you could dump the stream in a similar way to the way the font stream is written to file.

```
obj = fz_dict_gets(dict, "ToUnicode");
if (obj)
{
    stream = obj;
        buf = fz_new_buffer(0);

        error = pdf_load_stream(&buf, xref, fz_to_num(stream), fz_to_gen(stream));
        if (error)
        die(error);
            /* Do something with the data */
    }
```

buf->data (of size buf->len) would then contain the CMap, which you could write to file, or whatever.

Comment: Is this something Artifex or the MuPDF developers would consider to be added/included as an "official" feature of `mutool extract`?

Comment: If someone else wants to write the code, possibly yes, it seems to have some value. The developers don't have time at present.

Comment: Heh... it just looked to me non-coder like the code already is up there in this answer :-)

Comment: The bit that's missing is the comment marked 'Do something with the data'. Which is, of course, the hard part.....